# missing requirement osgi dependency resteasy multipart

Tags: java, osgi, pom.xml, resteasy, multipart

I am trying to include in a working osgi bundle rest easy jars for multipart. I am using a REST service which has input paramter of MultipartFormOutput. I have not been successful in fixing this issue from past 2 days. Am I missing some dependency or is there something I need to correct in my pom file. Snippets of my pom file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.integration.service,
                        com.integration.model
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also the dependecies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jsapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error I get:

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle mvn:com.xxx/xxxapi in feature(s) xxx-0.0.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.xxx.xxx-api [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:482)[49:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.1]
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:396)[49:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.1]
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:392)[49:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.1]
at org.apache.karaf.features.command.InstallFeatureCommand.doExecute(InstallFeatureCommand.java:62)[34:org.apache.karaf.features.command:2.3.1]
at org.apache.karaf.features.command.FeaturesCommandSupport.doExecute(FeaturesCommandSupport.java:41)[34:org.apache.karaf.features.command:2.3.1]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:174)[23:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.xxx-api [406]: Unable to resolve 406.0: missing requirement [406.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:931)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:479)[49:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.1]
... 15 more
```

Can someone guide what I am missing.

Comment: How did you install resteasy in karaf? Did you include resteasy-multipart-provider jar?

Comment: I have added resteasy jars and multipart provider jars in my pom file. Showed in the second image

Comment: Ok, but you still need to install the jars in karaf.. declaring them in your pom is not enough, because resteasy classes are not included in your bundle